# Refer to multiple hostnames in a Docker container using compose file

Tags: docker

We are running a bunch of services in their own containers via Docker, and we connect them using Docker Compose.

Previously we used **linking** to refer to other hosts, but the problem with that is that if a container is restarted and gets a new IP address then the linked nodes won't know about this and would stop working.

So we went with creating a network and naming our hosts and this works fine. However we have a mock component which we use for testing which replaces *two* of the other containers. I could configure this via links easily, but I don't know how to do this with networking.

Originally it was like:

```
mm:
  extends:
    file: common-service.yml
    service:  mm-container
  links:
    - mock:enet
    - mock:ff
```

(where `mm` is the container that knows about the containers `enet` and `ff`, and in this compose file used for testing we link them to the `mock` container instead.)

I tried adding this instead of the links:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "enet:mock"
  - "ff:mock"
```

(where `enet` and `ff` are the mocked hostnames) but of course this would add these lines to /etc/hosts as-is, so no hostname resolution takes place.

Is there a solution for this in Docker-land, or do we have to rewrite our mocking tool?

Answer (score 2):

You can define network aliases on your mock container. Everyone on the network with those aliases defined will see them, so you may need to adjust your networks to prevent other containers from seeing it. E.g.

```
version: '3'

networks:
  mocknet:

services:
  mm:
    image: mm:latest
    networks:
      default:
      mocknet:

  other_svc:
    image: other_image:latest

  mock:
    image: mock:latest
    networks:
      mocknet:
        aliases:
        - ff
        - enet
```

If everything in this stack is allowed to resolve ff and enet to the mock service, then you can do away with mocknet and just set the aliases on the default network.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's just two, you could give 'mock' one name and one hostname. Docker puts both of them in `/etc/hosts`

So, something like:

```
mock:
  [definitions of how to run 'mock']
  container_name: enet
  hostname: ff
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but doesn't quite work (on docker 1.9.0). The interesting part is that the container_name is registered in /etc/hosts, but not the hostname! Maybe there is something else that needs to be set?